# Query takes 28sec in phpmyadmin but mysql command line takes 662sec

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I've got a relatively simple query that selects the result of a stored function for a series of inputs based on the WHERE.  Full code is below.

What's stumping me is that when I invoke the query through the mysql cli, it takes 662sec to return 841 rows of a single column.  Now, if I copy/paste the exact same code into phpmyadmin, the same values return in just under 28sec.

*What do I need to do so that mysql executes this query as fast as phpmyadmin does?*

**WHAT I ALREADY TRIED:**

- Verified that both phpmyadmin and the php cli are using the same `EXPLAIN` plan.

  - `EXPLAIN` plans now included below.
- Verified that both phpmyadmin and the php cli are executing the query as the same user.
- Tested whether the mysql cli has better performance than the php cli.

  - **OUTCOME:** mysql cli returned values in 661sec, which was probably the same speed as the php cli.  I just realized that `SHOW PROCESSLIST` keeps counting time after the process goes to sleep.  *Question title and description above have been revised.*

**CURRENTLY EXPLORING:**

- Edit the stored function so that instead of using `WHERE IN` it uses `WHERE EXISTS`.

  - Suggested by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

**ENTIRE QUERY:** (includes non-problematic fields)

```
SELECT 
    EC_ITM_PULL.SKU_NUM, 
    EC_ITM_PULL.COLOR_CD, 
    GM_SKU.COLOR_DES, 
    GM_ITM.DES1, 
    GM_ITM.DES2, 
    CUSTOM.EC_GET_ONHAND(SUBSTRING(GM_SKU.SKU_NUM, 1, 9), GM_SKU.COLOR_CD) OH, 
    UPPER(EC_ITM_PULL.ITEM_PULLED_INIT) INIT, 
    CUSTOM.EC_MOST_RECENT_EVENT(SUBSTRING(GM_SKU.SKU_NUM, 1, 9), GM_SKU.COLOR_CD, 'E') EVENT_CD 
FROM 
    EC_ITM_PULL, 
    GM_MERCH.GM_SKU, 
    GM_INV.GM_ITM, 
    EC_ITM 
WHERE 
        EC_ITM.SKU_NUM = EC_ITM_PULL.SKU_NUM 
    AND EC_ITM_PULL.COLOR_CD = EC_ITM.COLOR_CD 
    AND EC_ITM_PULL.ITEM_PULLED IS NOT NULL 
    AND GM_ITM.ITM_CD = SUBSTRING(EC_ITM.SKU_NUM, 1, 9) 
    AND EC_ITM.SKU_NUM = GM_SKU.SKU_NUM 
    AND EC_ITM.TO_STUDIO IS NULL 
    AND GM_ITM.ITM_CD = SUBSTRING(EC_ITM_PULL.SKU_NUM, 1, 9);
```

**QUERY EXPLAIN PLAN:**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | EC_ITM_PULL | ALL    | SKU_NUM       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                | 2100 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | GM_ITM      | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 38      | func                                                |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | GM_SKU      | ref    | SKU_NUM       | SKU_NUM | 38      | CUSTOM.EC_ITM_PULL.SKU_NUM                          |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | EC_ITM      | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 58      | GM_MERCH.GM_SKU.SKU_NUM,CUSTOM.EC_ITM_PULL.COLOR_CD |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

**PROBLEMATIC STORED FUNCTION:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `EC_GET_ONHAND`(`N_ITM_CD` VARCHAR(12), `N_COLOR_CD` VARCHAR(6)) RETURNS smallint(5)
BEGIN
    DECLARE TOTALOH SMALLINT(5);

    IF N_COLOR_CD IS NULL THEN SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(RESERVE_QTY,0)+IFNULL(AVAIL_QTY,0)),0)
    INTO TOTALOH FROM GM_INV.GM_INV_LOC
    WHERE SKU_NUM 
    IN (
        SELECT SKU_NUM 
        FROM GM_MERCH.GM_SKU 
        WHERE ITM_CD = N_ITM_CD AND COLOR_CD IS NULL
    ) 
    AND (
        (
            (
                STORE_CD='85' 
                OR STORE_CD='95'
            ) 
            AND LOC_CD='STG72'
        ) 
        OR (
           (
               STORE_CD='72'
           ) 
           AND LOC_CD='RCV'
        )
    );

    ELSE SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(RESERVE_QTY,0)+IFNULL(AVAIL_QTY,0)),0)
    INTO TOTALOH 
    FROM GM_INV.GM_INV_LOC
    WHERE SKU_NUM
    IN (
        SELECT SKU_NUM 
        FROM GM_MERCH.GM_SKU 
        WHERE ITM_CD = N_ITM_CD 
        AND COLOR_CD = N_COLOR_CD)
        AND (
            (
                (
                    STORE_CD='85' 
                    OR STORE_CD='95'
                ) 
                AND LOC_CD='STG72'
            ) 
            OR (
                (
                    STORE_CD='72'
                ) 
                AND LOC_CD='RCV'
            )
        );

    END IF;

    RETURN TOTALOH;
END
```

**FUNCTION EXPLAIN PLAN:**

```
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type           | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref              | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | GM_INV_LOC | ALL            | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL             | 509791 | Using where              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | GM_SKU     | index_subquery | SKU_ITM_COLOR | SKU_ITM_COLOR | 97      | func,const,const |      1 | Using index; Using where |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Just a thought, but could it be something like different RAM allocation or stuff like that?

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan from the `explain` method? And some of the `mysqli` code?

Comment: are you performing any other action in your php function, from where you are executing this query ?

Comment: @salketer How should I go about diagnosing such an issue?  I am relatively new to database administration, unfortunately.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Of course, how silly of me.  I'll add that in with the rest of the updates I'm about to make.

Comment: @MTahir Not really.  All it does is send the sql and then iterate through the responses, pushing each row onto an array, which then gets json encoded and echoed back.  Its definitely hanging on the query because I can see it in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: how are you calculating time?

Comment: @MTahir Both phpmyadmin and mysql cli display execution time after the result of a query.  Last night I was using `SHOW PROCESSLIST` but didn't realize that it keeps counting time after a process goes to sleep so my original figure of 748sec is a bit inflated, as I didn't sit at my terminal hitting up, enter, up, enter... for 12 straight minutes.  The actual execution time is actually 628sec per the mysql cli.  I've corrected the question title and description to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by rewriting my stored function.  This actually reduced the query time all the way down to 1.19sec, so I actually made it even faster than phpmyadmin =)

First I took the advice of the linked article in the question and edited this part:

```
WHERE SKU_NUM 
    IN (
        SELECT SKU_NUM 
        FROM GM_MERCH.GM_SKU 
        WHERE ITM_CD = N_ITM_CD AND COLOR_CD IS NULL
    )
```

to this:

```
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM GM_MERCH.GM_SKU, GM_INV.GM_INV_LOC
        WHERE 
            ITM_CD = N_ITM_CD 
        AND COLOR_CD IS NULL
        AND GM_INV_LOC.SKU_NUM = GM_MERCH.SKU_NUM
    )
```

That reduced the execution time of the query to just under 180sec, but caused the function to return incorrect values because it was repeating the addition for each row in the subquery.

So then it occurs to me that maybe I shouldn't be using a subquery at all.  I rewrote the lookup in the function as follows:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(RESERVE_QTY,0)+IFNULL(AVAIL_QTY,0)),0)
    INTO TOTALOH FROM GM_INV.GM_INV_LOC, GM_MERCH.SKU_NUM
    WHERE 
        ITM_CD = N_ITM_CD 
    AND COLOR_CD IS NULL
    AND GM_INV_LOC.SKU_NUM = GM_SKU.SKU_NUM
    AND (
        (
            (
                STORE_CD='85' 
                OR STORE_CD='95'
            ) 
            AND LOC_CD='STG72'
        ) 
        OR (
           (
               STORE_CD='72'
           ) 
           AND LOC_CD='RCV'
        )
    );
```

The whole big query now returns its 841 rows in 1.19sec with accurate values.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you found the solution. But having different times between phpmyadmin, another php application or just cli usually means that the settings are not the same everywhere. According to your difference in times, but without knowing the size of the data handled, it might be because your CLI lacks memory and needs to SWAP... To verify your different "mysql accessing environments" I suggest you run these queries and compare the results:

```
show variables like max_heap_table_size #chances are you will find diff here
show variables #shows all variables
```

Hope it might help someone who stumble on this kind of figure.